# Runtime drawing subsystem icon based on output results

Tags: simulink

Does someone know a way how to update/draw subsystem's input or output results in runtime? In this sense, one could do a Scope block, which updates itself during the simulation, so one could see the results already by looking at the block.

Of course, my intention is not making a scope block but make some custom drawings based on results inside the subsystem in runtime.

This would mean either to:

- be able to access a variable with results in `plot` command of masked subsystem and making sure that Simulink calls refresh everytime the variable changes
- change `MaskDisplay` from outside, for example by inputting absolute values in  `plot` command and signaling to Simulink that it needs to refresh that Subsystem's drawing

Answer (score 0):

One way of to use a MATLAB Function block and declare plot, for example, as an extrinsic:

```
coder.extrinsic('plot');
```

You can then use plot in the MATLAB Function. You can also do this for a custom MATLAB file:

```
coder.extrinsic('my_custom_draw_function');
```

Somewhat more complicated can be to use m-file s-function.